# Text is selected automatically on element focus on some browsers

Tags: jquery, focus

I have this automatically searching text input, which makes a new search when user types a letter. Now I have to focus to this element after every search, but I in all browsers except Firefox, text in input is selected. If user types another letter, then selected text is erased and this will mean that user must unselect text before user can type in another letter. Of course user will type new letter and think that there is something wrong with this program.

Is it possible to unselect text on focus or prevent this selection happening at the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning the value of the textbox to itself on focus will unselect the text.

```
$('input').focus(function() { 
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.val(elem.val());
} );
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/SkGYS/)

Comment: Thanx for this, but in IE there is problem, that when unfocused and focused again, it will start to write test at start of text in input ...

Comment: @newbie: I see what you mean now, IE9 jumps the cursor back to the beginning of the `input`. What version are you using?

Comment: IE8, but this is normal for IE, nothing works out of the box, it always needs fixies

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure but I think this could be a solution or simply use the attribute `onselect="return;"`

```
$('#selector').select(function (e){
   e.preventDefault();
   return;
});
```

Comment: what chrome version u using ?

Comment: @town Im using the same version the demo u provided works for myself

Comment: How bizarre! Well, I'm stumped. Over to Google... :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with following code:

```
var searchInput = $('input.search');
var l = searchInput.val().length;
searchInput.attr('selectionStart', l);
searchInput.attr('selectionEnd', l);
searchInput.focus();
```

Comment: Definitely not working for me on Chrome 11.0.696.65.  I'd recommend using my solution (not that I'm biased or anything! ;) ) as `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are not consistent cross-browser.